# Pass a string as the second argument to transform

Tags: r, transform

I want to write a function that creates new variables in a dataframe based on strings read from a SQL table. The function should take two arguments, `df` and `str`, and return `df` with an extra column appended. `str` will be string of the form `"a = f(B)"`, where `a` is a column of `df`, `B` is a set of columns of `df`, and `f` is the transformation function.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(EventID = c(111,112,113), Day = c(6,8,15))
```

What I want is `transform(df, Week = ceiling(Day / 7))`, but I can't figure out how to pass the string `"Week = ceiling(Day / 7)"` (as a variable of type character) to the `...` arguments of `transform`.

I've tried various combinations of `parse` and `eval`, but I can't figure out how to change a character object into what the R documentation describes as a "tagged vector expression."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
fun <- function(df, str.expression) within(df, eval(parse(text=str.expression)))

fun(df, "Week = ceiling(Day / 7)")
#   EventID Day Week
# 1     111   6    1
# 2     112   8    2
# 3     113  15    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out pretty quick, but I'll still share: `eval(parse())` the whole thing!

```
eval(parse(text = paste("transform(df,", str, ")", sep = "")))
```

That said, I like @flodel's answer better.

Comment: It might be  easier to use `sprintf('transform(df, %s )', str)` to construct your call